# What is the category of Heyting valued set with functional relations from the logic point of view?

Tags: logic, category-theory

A few years ago i proved, to pass an exam, that, given a topological space $S$, the category of sheaves over $S$ is equivalent to the category of $Open(S)-set$ with functional relations.

The open sets of a topology form a complete Heyting algebra; what is, from the logic point of view, an $Open(S)-set$?
What does functional relations represents in that view?
Is there any reference for this?
*I've found something about Hetyng valued models of intuitionistic set theory; i am not sure if this is the point*

> **Some definitions:**
> Let $S$ be a topological space and $Open(S)$ the set of its opens.
> An $Open(S)-set$ is a pair $(X,\rho)$ where:
> $X$ is a $set$; and
> $\rho:X\times X\rightarrow Open(S)$ is a function that satisfies $\rho(x,y)=\rho(y,x)$ and $\rho(x,y)\cap \rho(y,z)\subseteq \rho(x,z)$ $for\;all$ $x,y,z\in X$.

> A morphism between $(X,\rho_X)$ and $(Y,\rho_Y)$ is a function $F:X\times Y\longrightarrow Open(S)$ that satisfies:
> (i) $F(x,y)\subseteq \rho_X(x,x)\cap \rho_Y(y,y)$ for every $(x,y)\in X\times Y$;
> (ii) $F(x,y)\cap\rho_X(x,x')\cap\rho_Y(y,y')\subseteq F(x',y')$ for every $(x,x',y,y')\in X^2\times Y^2$;
> (iii) $F(x,y)\cap F(x,y')\subseteq \rho_Y(y,y')$ for every $(x,y,y')\in X\times Y\times Y$; and
> (iv) $\rho_X(x,x)\subseteq \cup_{y\in Y}F(x,y)$ for every $x\in X$

> Given $F:X\times Y\longrightarrow Open(S)$ e $G:Y\times Z\longrightarrow Open(S)$ functional realtions between $Open(S)-sets$ one can verify that $cmp(F,G)(x,z):=\cup_{y\in Y}F(x,y)\cap G(y,z)$ is a functional relation called the *composition of $F$ and $G$*.

> With does data one defines the category $Open(S)_{FR}$ with objects the $Open(S)-sets$ and morphism the functional relations.

Comment: You are looking at a special case of the tripos-to-topos construction. The tripos is the functor sending a set $S$ to $O(X)^S$.

Comment: I've read something about what you say (n-lab) but it is too much syntetic. Some dubts that i have now are the following: 1) What does it means that $Set$ is assumed to be the category of terms (to construct a tripos over a complete Heyting Algebra)? 2) It is not very clear how one can construct from that tripos an $H-valued$ $set$. I think i refer to the Higgs theorem. The fact is that i have never treat the argument in an organig way. I don't know if exists some notes about the argument. Thanks.